# How to set up Easy Permissions for BLUETOOTH_SCAN in a app in Android Studio

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-permissions, android-bluetooth, android-12

The app is using Easy Permissions Library to set up the permissions for the app. The location permission is already setup. Tried piggybacking off of the Location setup, but it's not working. I have the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission in the app and you can turn it on in the App Settings, but I need it to pop up to ask the user when they are in that part of the app.

Here's the code:

```
abstract class BaseBeaconScanDialogFragment: BaseDialogFragment(), OnParentActivityResultListener,
    EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{
    companion object {
        const val TAG = "BeaconScanDialogFrgmnt"
        private const val REQ_BEACON_SCAN_PERMISSION = 300
        const val REQ_TURN_ON_BLUETOOTH = 301
        const val REQ_TURN_ON_LOCATION = 302
        const val REQ_TURN_ON_BEACON_SCAN = 303

        const val BT_SCAN_TIMEOUT = 10L // 5s
    }

    private lateinit var tracsNotificationManager: TracsNotificationManager

    val bleScanUseCase: BleScanUseCase = BleScanUseCase.create()

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (activity is MainActivity) {
            (activity as MainActivity).setOnParentActivityResultListener(this)
        }

        tracsNotificationManager = (requireContext().applicationContext as TracsApplication)
                .appComponent.tracsNotificationManager()
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        if (activity is MainActivity) {
            (activity as MainActivity).setOnParentActivityResultListener(null)
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    protected fun turnOnBeaconScanService() {
        if (!BtScanSettingVerifyUtil.verifyLocation(requireContext())) {
            buildSettingAlertDialog("Please enable location setting",
                    getString(R.string.ok)) {
                turnOnLocation()
            }
        } else if (!BtScanSettingVerifyUtil.verifyBluetooth()) {
            buildSettingAlertDialog("Please enable Bluetooth Setting",
                    getString(R.string.enable_button_text)) {
                turnOnBluetooth()
            }
        } else if (!BtScanSettingVerifyUtil.hasLocationPermissions(requireContext())) {
            buildSettingAlertDialog("Please grant location permission to scan nearby " +
                    "BT reader",
                    getString(R.string.grant_permission_button_text)) {
                requestLocationPermission()
            }
        } else if (!BtScanSettingVerifyUtil.hasBluetoothScanPermissions(requireContext())){
            buildSettingAlertDialog("Please grant Bluetooth Scan to scan nearby" +
                    "BT Reader",
                getString(R.string.grant_permission_button_text)){
                requestBluetoothScanPermission()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun buildSettingAlertDialog(alertMessage: String, positiveButtonText: String,
                                        onPositiveButtonClick: () -> Unit) {
        GeneralRmaDialogFragment.Builder(requireContext())
                .setBodyText(alertMessage)
                .setPositiveButtonText(positiveButtonText)
                .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.cancel))
                .setNegativeButtonVisible(true)
                .setListener(object : GeneralRmaDialogFragment.RmaDialogButtonClickListener {
                    override fun clickPositiveButton() {
                        onPositiveButtonClick()
                    }

                    override fun clickNegativeButton() {
                        dismiss()
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show(childFragmentManager)
    }

    protected fun turnOffBeaconScanService() {
        try {
            bleScanUseCase.stopScan(requireContext().applicationContext)
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            context?.let { Toast.makeText(it, t.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }
        } finally {
            beaconScanServiceStatusChange(false)
        }
    }

    // call when the status of BT scan service change
    protected abstract fun beaconScanServiceStatusChange(isOn: Boolean)

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>,
                                            grantResults: IntArray) {
        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onParentActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_TURN_ON_BLUETOOTH && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("bt_setting", "onActivityResult: bt")
            turnOnBeaconScanService()
        } else if (requestCode == REQ_TURN_ON_LOCATION && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("bt_setting", "onActivityResult: location")
            turnOnBeaconScanService()
        }
    }

    private fun turnOnBluetooth() {
        Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE).also {
            activity?.startActivityForResult(it, REQ_TURN_ON_BLUETOOTH)
        }
    }

    private fun turnOnLocation() {
        activity?.let { GpsUtils(it).turnGPSOn(REQ_TURN_ON_LOCATION) {} }
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    override fun onPermissionsDenied(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)){
            SettingsDialog.Builder(requireActivity()).build().show()
        }else{
            requestLocationPermission()
            requestBluetoothScanPermission()
        }
    }

    override fun onPermissionsGranted(requestCode: Int, perms: List<String>) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Location permission granted")
    }

    private fun requestLocationPermission() {
        if (LocationPermissionUtil.hasLocationPermission(requireContext())) {
            return
        }
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "Please grant location permission to scan nearby BT reader",
            REQ_BEACON_SCAN_PERMISSION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        )
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    private fun requestBluetoothScanPermission(){
        if (BluetoothPermissionUtil.hasBluetoothPermission(requireContext())){
            return
        }
        EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(
            this,
            "Please grant Bluetooth permission to scan nearby BT reader",
            REQ_TURN_ON_BEACON_SCAN,
            android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
            android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
            android.Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
        )
    }
}
```

The VerifyUtil

```
public class BtScanSettingVerifyUtil {

    public static boolean verifyBluetooth() {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        // Bluetooth is not enabled :)
        // Bluetooth is enabled
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Device does not support Bluetooth
            return false;
        } else {
            return mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();
        }

    }

    public static boolean verifyLocation(@NonNull Context context) {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean gps_enabled;
        boolean network_enabled;
        if (lm == null) {
            return false;
        }

        gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        // either gps enable or network enable is ok for beacon scan
        return gps_enabled || network_enabled;
    }

    public static boolean hasLocationPermissions(@NotNull Context context) {
        boolean hasLocationPermission = true;
        String[] locationPermissions = getSDKPermissionArray();

        for (String permission : locationPermissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                hasLocationPermission = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return hasLocationPermission;
    }

    public static boolean hasBluetoothScanPermissions(@NotNull Context context){
        boolean hasBluetoothScanPermission = true;
        String[] bluetoothScanPermissions = getSDKPermissionArray();

        for (String permission : bluetoothScanPermissions){
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                hasBluetoothScanPermission = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return hasBluetoothScanPermission;
    }

    public static final String[] SDK_PERMISSION_LIST
            = new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

    public static String[] getSDKPermissionArray() {
        return SDK_PERMISSION_LIST;
    }

}
```

Bluetooth Util

```
public class BluetoothPermissionUtil {

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
    public static boolean hasBluetoothPermission(@NonNull Context context){
        return EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
        );
    }
}
```

These are the code that I used to bring the Permission to the UI, so that the user can accept it that way, but right now, I can turn it on through the App setting. Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I never worked with easy permissions before, but in case you can't find a solution to your problem requesting permissions at runtime is not that complicated: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java